# node js for each dataset, connect database, perform select, update, insert query asynchronously

Tags: node.js, sql-server, testing, automation, testcafe

I am working on testcafe, in one of the data-driven test cases, for each test case, I am performing below set of database operations, connect, select, update, insert, close connection.
The issue is when I execute forEach loop with only one dataset, it works well when I have multiple datasets, it fails with below error -

> ConnectionError: Already connecting to database! Call close before
>   connecting to different database.
>       at ConnectionPool._connect (C:\javelin\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:238:37)
>       at PromiseLibrary (C:\javelin\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:220:19)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at ConnectionPool.connect (C:\javelin\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:219:12)
>       at C:\javelin\tests\order-scoring\order-scoring-promisified.js:49:44
>       at new Promise ()
>       at new F (C:\javelin\node_modules\core-js\library\modules_export.js:36:28)
>       at Request. (C:\javelin\tests\order-scoring\order-scoring-promisified.js:48:20)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (C:\javelin\node_modules\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, the database module you are using does not allow you to perform multiple database connections. This issue doesn't relate to TestCafe.

Please check that your database module allows multiple concurrent database connections and tweak it correspondingly.